# Emoji keyboard layout is not drawing correctly and is missing many emojis

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

[**My app's virtual keyboard for emojis is looking really messed up.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2oYL.png)

The keyboard looks perfectly normal on all other apps on my phone, as well as new projects I tested. The code is simply:

```
UITextField *textField = [UITextField new];
[otherView addSubview:textField];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

It does not matter if I use a UITextField or a UITextView.
**What can cause this type of behavior?**

Some search terms I tried before asking this question (for other people who have this problem): w3c icon placeholder bug uikeyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by removing files until the keyboard started functioning properly again!

Turned out that (in my **NSString category**) a method I named `+(NSString*)stringWithUnichar:(unichar)value;` was a **private method** that is apparently used by the Emoji UIKeyboard.

After I renamed the method to `+(NSString*)unicharToString:(unichar)value;`, the emojis were all restored, but the page number indicators (the dots on the top of the keyboard) were still misplaced.

I looked further and found my **UIView category** had an interfering method name too. It was named `- (void) setOrigin:(CGPoint)origin;`. That was probably bad use of categories anyway...

**Moral of the story:** Be careful with your method names in categories of Apple's frameworks!

Here's a relevant article by Apple on ["Naming Methods"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/codingguidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1003829). Right at the end, it discusses private methods and **attaching prefixes to methods when subclassing the Cocoa framework**. It is a bummer Apple doesn't follow their own advice. Instead, they just pass on this unnecessary burden to the developer... This problem would've never occurred if NSString's `stringWithUnichar:` was named `APPLE_stringWithUnichar:`, for example.

Comment: This is why we use prefixes for classes and category methods.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice for the developers if Apple prefixed their private methods? :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if Objective-C could get namespace support? :D